# How to call a local host, by socket... rather than by IP

Tags: php, sockets

Actually I make my first steps on sockets, with PHP, locally.

In my `hosts`, I have a virtual domain named `chat.dev.com`.

I have seen a lot of examples by IP... but is it possible to call a specific local subdomain, please, rather than my `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: I tried around the second example on http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

But It doesn't seems to pass by the .htaccess

Comment: In my configuration, all the subdomains are managed by .htaccess (https://github.com/Lcfvs/DOMArch/blob/master/.htaccess)

Comment: Please show us your code and what error you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets are identified by a combination of an IP address and a port. In order to try to connect to a DNS, as you seem to imply, you first need to make a DNS lookup for that specific host, get its associated IP address and then connect.

Php has a function for this, please look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php

Comment: Aaah, thanks for this answer a few more in the right direction :)
So, it pushes me to think the sockets aren't the solution I search.
Is there another solution, working like sockets (keep-alive connections) based on http? Origininally, I thought to something like that https://gist.github.com/Lcfvs/9829c60cc56dd65b394c71d8d8e4ad9e

Comment: This totally depends on what you are trying to create. If you explained it briefly I might be able to help you further.

Comment: Ok, thanks... I'm trying to rely 2 "servers" to exchange some messages (on a living connection) but, if possible, passing by my .htaccess configuration... just like we call a website, from a browser, then

Comment: If what you looking it is passing HTTP messages between the two servers, I would take a look at PHPs cURL library. cURL is made to send custom HTTP messages from the command line but has since then been adapted to other uses.

Comment: Hum, ok... for example, by an event stream, then, like for the Server-Sent-Events?